# What is the performance of BigQuery federated queries?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am re-designing a service so that large data sets can searched using BigQuery. Originally, I was going to set up a process to stream data from CloudSQL to BigQuery each evening but I became aware of federated queries during the research phase. Perhaps I missing something obvious but I cant seem to find anything that specifically notes if BigQuery federated queries are as performative as normal BigQuery queries. It seems to focus on the problem of storing data in multiple systems and federated queries making it easier to join MySQL (or Postgres) data with BigQuery data.

Do federated queries leverage all or most of the advantages of BigQuery (using thousands of machines to perform scans) or is that not possible? Google says "*May not perform as well as querying data residing in BigQuery tables" but has anyone used this and found it to be close to or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance is limited to your CloudSQL instance's capacity. That's your bottleneck.

For sure you already read [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#overview) but gathering the information from different sections you can see that what actually happens is the following.

BigQuery will send a query to be executed at your CloudSQL instance. 
The results of the query will be read by BigQuery and stored in a temporary table.

Keep in mind, this means you are putting some load in your CloudSQL instance, and also you need to read bytes (and pay for them) in BigQuery.

This is clearly different from using one of the commercial tools like StitchData or Fivetran to replicate your CloudSQL data in BigQuery and **then** querying it directly in BigQuery.